# Create a group for users and sets the permission

Tags: linux, permissions, user-accounts

I would like to create group for some user

> addgroup name

After that I would like to add some user to group

> sudo adduser username groupname

And set the permission for each group. There will be three groups:
1st: Group administrators, with permission r,w,e
2nd : Group of users, they could copy, insert new file, but no rewrite and delete
3rd: Group of viewers, they could only read.
It will be for folder with subfolders.
Could you help me with settings of perrmisions?
Thanks a lot
Filip

Comment: I believe it might be beneficial to do some Internet searches about basic UNIX/Linux/BSD user/group management and access control lists. The latter is the actual thing that you will use to produce a fine grained control over a directory for several groups (UNIX-like permissions only have bits for one group per directory).